# How to uncommit in mercurial for my last commit(not yet pushed)

Tags: mercurial

I have situation like this:

> I have commited files a,b,c,d.Now i found that by mistake i commited
>   files a and b; so before pushing these changes, i want to do uncommit 
>   files a and b so that i can push only c and d.Can someone tell me how
>   to do that by using mercurial commands.

Here uncommit means that i dunt want to use "hg out -p" and after that
 looking change set and do things manually.

Comment: Comparing this and the question marked a duplicate, it's clear that this is a different situation with a different answer. Rather than looking to delete a changeset, we want to convert it to a set of uncommitted file changes with the intention of creating a new, altered changeset.

Comment: Since no more answers can be added here and this really isn't the same question, to remove files from an uncommit on state-of-the-art mercurial, just enable the [`evolve`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html) extension and use the `uncommit` command. The `-i` flag will allow you to select each file/hunk/line you want to uncommit and those changes be removed from the commit while being kept on the working directory.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Assuming you haven't performed any other transactions on your repository since you committed the files, I think you could do this as a 2 stage process:

```
hg rollback
hg commit filec filed
```

`hg rollback` should remove the commit that you have just made, but leave the files as changed.  Then `hg commit filec filed` should commit the files named `filec` & `filed`.  Obviously you should replace these file names with the names of your actual files.

It's probably worth mentioning that you should be careful with `hg rollback` - it alters the history, so it is possible to lose data with it if used incorrectly.

Comment: rollback is deprecated and marked as dangerous. A simple way to 'uncommit' your last commit is to use hg strip -r -1 -k.

Comment: Since people gave me a -1 for that comment. Here is the documentation that backs up my claim: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/rollback

Comment: In case the link breaks, the documentation mentioned by @phb states: _[hg rollback](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/rollback) Roll back the last transaction (DANGEROUS) (DEPRECATED) Please use 'hg commit --amend' instead of rollback to correct mistakes in the last commit._ Importantly, `hg commit --amend` is the recommended alternative!

Answer (score 4):

`hg rollback`, and you can find more in the [Chapter 9. Finding and fixing mistakes](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html) of the [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/)

Answer (score 3):

In mercurial you can use the backout command, which creates a changeset that is the opposite of the changeset you want to backed out. Then this changeset is committed. The only thing you need to do after that is a merge.

You can backout any changeset, but it's not recommended to backout a merge changeset.

A detailed explanation of the command with an example can be found [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout).

Comment: This is really handy for those times that rollback won't work because you ```--amend```ed the commit.